# Why is it that I cannot sort my grid in jqgrid everytime I clicked the column header?

Tags: jquery, sorting, jqgrid-php, client-side

I was really confused that my program using jqgrid won't sort (descending) everytime I clicked the column header? I tried creating a program where I use local data (.json data) and it work great in sorting when I clicked the column header. So what's the problem with the first one? I am using the data from client server....

Here's my javascript code:

```
  $("#btnQueryMainAccountGroups").click( function() {
    var params = {
      "SessionID": $("#eSessionID3").val(),
      "dataType": "data"
    }
    $('#tblData').setGridParam({
      url:'process.php?path=' + encodeURI('masterData/data') + '&json=' + encodeURI(JSON.stringify(params)), 
      datatype: olSettings.ajaxDataType,  
    });
    $('#tblData').trigger('reloadGrid');
    }); 

    $("#tblData").jqGrid({
    url: '',
    datatype: '',
    jsonReader : {
      root: function(obj) {
        var root = [];

    if  ('error' in obj) 
    {
      showMessage(obj.error['class'] + ' error: ' + obj['error']['msg']);
    }
    else
    {
      $.each(obj['result']['main']['rowdata'], function(rowIndex, rowDataValue) {
        var row = {};
        $.each(rowDataValue, function(columnIndex, rowArrayValue) {
          var fldName = obj['result']['main']['metadata']['fields'][columnIndex].name;
          row[fldName] = rowArrayValue;                
        });
        root[rowIndex] = row;
      });
    };
    return root;
  },
  page: "result.main.page",
  total: "result.main.pageCount",
  records: "result.main.rows",
  repeatitems: false,
  id: "0"
},
serializeGridData: function(postData) {
  var jsonParams = {
    'SessionID': $('#eSessionID3').val(),
    'dataType': 'data',
    'recordLimit': postData.rows,
    'recordOffset': postData.rows * (postData.page - 1),
    'rowDataAsObjects': false,
    'queryRowCount': true,
    'sort_fields': postData.sidx
  };

  return 'json=' + JSON.stringify(jsonParams);
},

},
colNames:['ID','Code', 'Description','Type'],
colModel:[
  {name:'group_id'},
  {name:'group_code',align:'center',width:100},
  {name:'group_desc'},
  {name:'type'}
],

viewrecords: true,
rowList:[5,10,50,100],
pager: '#tblDataPager',
sortname: 'group_desc',
sortorder: 'asc',
rowNum:5,
loadonce:false,
caption: "MainGroup"
});

$("#tblData").setGridWidth($(window).width() - 70);
$("#tblData").jqGrid('sortableRows');
```

that's my code in javascript where i can't sort my jqgrid...
my process.php code:

```
 <?php 
     print(file_get_contents("http://localhost/" .... "?json=" . $_GET["json"]));
 ?>
```

There's no problem in loading of data to the jqgrid. The only problem is that I cannot sort them in descending order. Everytime i clicked a column header, it only sorts ascending, and if i clicked again, no descending happen. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should use **sortable: true** in your required fields' colModel as follows:

```
colModel:[
 {name:'group_id', sortable: true},
 {name:'group_code',align:'center',width:100, sortable: true},
 {name:'group_desc', sortable: true},
 {name:'type', sortable: true}
],
```

You should now able to sort properly.

Answer (score 0):

When using data from server, you must provide ready-to-use data: both ordered and paginated.

To do so, jqgrid sends in the request the variables `sidx` and `sord` , containing the name of the column and the ordering ('desc' for descending).

See the [tutorial](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3afirst_grid) for further help and a PHP example.

Comment: hey, how can i store a password, username and a database in one php file.? i already had this code, configdb.php

    <?
        $dbuser = "root";
        $dbpassword = "somepassword";
    ?>
    
my database is in another php file...
    
    <?php
      print(file_get_contents("http://localhost:8001/" . $_GET["path"] . "?json=" . urlencode($_GET["json"])));
    ?>
    
how can i make this two into one .php file... 
    
    thank you Don...

Comment: by the way, i'm using pgAdmin:PostgreSQL

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know PHP. I'm using jqGrid with Python and Django

Comment: i already study the tutorial and i guess i didn't miss anything.. <link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="js/css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="js/css/ui.jqgrid.custom.css" />  
  <script type="javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="javascript" src="js/js/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js"></script>
 <script type="javascript" src="js/grid.base.js"></script>  
  <script type="javascript" src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"</script>
  <script type="javascript" src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"</script>
  did i miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Try using **`loadonce:true`;**, 
You are using **loadonce:false**.

It says in [here,](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options)

`If this flag is set to true, the grid loads the data from the server only once (using the appropriate datatype). After the first request, the datatype parameter is automatically changed to local and all further manipulations are done on the client side. The functions of the pager (if present) are disabled.`